# VB.NET Imports. How to import a namespace to a web page with a server-side VB script

Tags: vb.net, import

I am trying to figure out this example code written in VB. What I cannot understand is how do I import this missing namespace. Below is the code.

```
<!-- directives -->
<% @Page Language="VB" %>
<% @Import Namespace="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider" %>
<!-- code section -->
<script runat="server">
    Public Function GetAmtFillZeros(ByVal text As String) As String
        Return Trim(text.Replace(".", "")).PadLeft(12, "0"c)
    End Function

    Public Function GenerateOrderId() As Integer
        Return 10567
    End Function

    Public Function ComputeHash(ByVal Key As String) As String
        Dim objSHA1 As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()
    objSHA1.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Key.ToCharArray))
        Dim buffer() As Byte = objSHA1.Hash
        Dim HashValue As String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)
        Return HashValue
    End Function
    ....
```

Here, the line `Dim objSHA1 As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()` causes a compilation error `BC30002: Type 'SHA1CryptoServiceProvider' is not defined.`. What I don't understand is the reason for that. Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import needs to be
`System.Security.Cryptography` not with a method in the imports

```
<!-- directives -->
<% @Page Language="VB" %>
<% @Import Namespace="System.Security.Cryptography" %>
 <!-- code section -->
<script runat="server">
Public Function GetAmtFillZeros(ByVal text As String) As String
    Return Trim(text.Replace(".", "")).PadLeft(12, "0"c)
End Function

Public Function GenerateOrderId() As Integer
    Return 10567
End Function

Public Function ComputeHash(ByVal Key As String) As String
    Dim objSHA1 As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()
objSHA1.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Key.ToCharArray))
    Dim buffer() As Byte = objSHA1.Hash
    Dim HashValue As String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)
    Return HashValue
End Function
....
```

Comment: should your functions not be surrounded by a class?

Comment: Well.. Actually I am not sure. But the thing works fine when I replace `Dim objSHA1 As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()` with `Dim objSHA1 As New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()` and takes out the import statement. So I presume it's a problem with how I put the import statement..

Comment: `<%@ Page Language="VB" %>`
    `<%@ Import Namespace ="System.Security.Cryptography" %>`

Comment: Extremely sorry that I was this late to review this answer and more than that being a complete idiot to not to see that imports won't work like this `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider` which you put the whole damn FQ class name in the import!